# Angular CDK/Material tags showing as not a known element in VSCode with Angular Language Service

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cdk, angular-language-service

I'm seeing errors showing up in my HTML file where I use Angular CDK tags as shown in screenshot below in VSCode with Angular Language Service installed:
[image]

I have imported the cdk module into my app module as well:
[image]

Tried with Angular material as well and it's showing the same error without any intellisense suggestion. I'm able to run ng serve without any errors though.
Anyone has any idea to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use Legacy View Engine language service]

Go to Angular Language Service extension settings and close View-engine

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the TS version to the bottom right of your editor matches the TS version in your package.json file ? I had strange highlighting behaviors with outmatching TS version

Comment: Seems there is no typescript version showing in the bottom right of the editor. Only show the type of file. I've tried to go to command palette and see what version I'm using and its showing I'm using 4.4.3 which is what as specified in package.json. I've got another project added into VSCode that has those MatTable tags but has no error popping up on those tags. The project is using 3.5.3 version. I tried change to 3.5.3 for my project that has the error but it still showing up.